Finding an analytical solution to the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x-c} e^{-bx} \sin(rx) \, dx$
I use residue theorem to solve the following definite integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x-c} e^{-bx} \sin(rx) \,dx$$ where $b$ and $r$ are real numbers, and $c$ is a complex number. And
$\mathrm{Re}(c)>0$, $\mathrm{Im}(c)<0$, $b>0$, $r>0$.
Using Residue Theorem from complex analysis:
Step 1: Consider the Complex Integral
The integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x-c} e^{-(b-ir)x} \, dx$ has a simple pole at $x = c$ in the right half of the complex plane.
Step 2: Choose the Contour
Since the real part of $c$ is positive, the pole $x = c$ is in the right half-plane. We choose a contour $C$ in the lower half-plane, which is a semicircle of radius $R$ and let $R\to \infty$. The contour consists of two parts: the real axis from $0\to R$ and the semicircular arc.
Step 3: Calculate the Residue
The residue at the pole $x = c$ is:
$$
\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{x-c} e^{-(b-ir)x}, c\right) = \lim_{x \to c} (x - c) \frac{1}{x-c} e^{-(b-ir)x} = e^{-(b-ir)c} = e^{-bc} e^{-irc}
$$
Step 4: Apply the Residue Theorem
By the residue theorem, the integral over the closed contour is:
$$
\oint_C \frac{1}{x-c} e^{-(b-ir)x} \, dx = -2\pi i \, \text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{x-c} e^{-(b-ir)x}, c\right) = -2\pi i e^{-bc} e^{-irc}
$$
The negative sign comes from the fact that the contour is traversed clockwise in the lower half-plane.
Step 5: Evaluate the Real Integral
As $R \to \infty$, the integral over the semicircular arc goes to zero because the exponential function $e^{-(b-ir)x}$ decays rapidly in the lower half-plane. Therefore, we have:
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x-c} e^{-(b-ir)x} \, dx = -2\pi i e^{-bc} e^{-irc}
$$
Step 6: Take the Imaginary Part
Finally, we take the imaginary part to get the value of the original integral:
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x-c} e^{-bx} \sin(rx) \, dx = \text{Im}\left(-2\pi i e^{-bc} e^{-irc}\right)
$$
Step 7: Calculate the Imaginary Part
Calculate the imaginary part of $-2\pi i e^{-bc} e^{-irc}$:
$$
-2\pi i e^{-bc} e^{-irc} = -2\pi i e^{-bc} (\cos(rc) - i \sin(rc)) = -2\pi e^{-bc} (-\sin(rc) - i \cos(rc))
$$
The imaginary part is:
$$
\text{Im}\left(-2\pi e^{-bc} (-\sin(rc) - i \cos(rc))\right) = -2\pi e^{-bc} \cos(rc)
$$
Step 8: Verification
I use GNU Octave quadgk function to verify the result and it does not match. Can't figure out the mistake in those steps. Or maybe Residue Theorem is NOT suitable for solving this integral.
Hoping to point out the issues. Appreciate the assistance!
Sean

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

with Maple: $\frac{\mathrm{I}}{4} \left(\left(-2 ,\mathrm{Ei}{1}! \left(c \left(b -\mathrm{I} r \right)\right)-\ln ! \left(\frac{1}{c}\right)+\ln ! \left(c \right)+2 \ln ! \left(b -\mathrm{I} r \right)-2 \ln ! \left(c \left(b -\mathrm{I} r \right)\right)\right) {\mathrm e}^{c \left(b -\mathrm{I} r \right)}+\left(2 ,\mathrm{Ei}{1}! \left(c \left(b +r \mathrm{I}\right)\right)+\ln ! \left(\frac{1}{c}\right)-\ln ! \left(c \right)-2 \ln ! \left(b +r \mathrm{I}\right)+2 \ln ! \left(c \left(b +r \mathrm{I}\right)\right)\right) {\mathrm e}^{c \left(b +r \mathrm{I}\right)}\right)
$

Assuming $b>0\land r>0\land \Re(c)>0\land \Im(c)<0$, Mathematica evaluates the Laplace transform as $$\mathcal{L}_x\left\frac{\sin (r x)}{x-c}\right=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-b x} \sin (r x)}{x-c} , dx=\frac{1}{2} e^{-c (b+i r)} \left(\pi+e^{2 i c r} (\pi+i, \text{Ei}(c (b-i r)))-i, \text{Ei}(c (b+i r))\right)=e^{-c b} \left(\pi  \cos(c r)+\frac{1}{2} i \left(e^{i c r} \text{Ei}(c (b-i r))-e^{-i c r} \text{Ei}(c (b+i r))\right)\right).$$
